Proving a system is time invariant
Given the following system
$$ y’(t) + t\,y(t) = x(t) $$
My notes gave the following steps and concluded the system is time variant instead.

I do not get the statement saying the following “$y_0(t)$ and $y(t - t_0)$ are solutions to DIFFERENT differential equations.” What does it mean by different differential equations in this context?

The system is given by a differential equation, and they say when you delay the input vs delaying the output you don’t get the same differential equation (ie you don’t get the same system), hence the system is time variant

Well, $y_0(t)$ is a solution to
$$y'+ty=x(t-t_0)\tag{1}$$
whereas $y(t-t_0)$ is a solution to
$$y'+(t-t_0)y=x(t-t_0)\tag{2}$$
Clearly, $(1)$ and $(2)$ are different, hence the conclusion.
